# DocuSign error code ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE without server template, succeeds with server template

Tags: docusignapi

The following request body returns error code: `ENVELOPE_IS_INCOMPLETE`

> The Envelope is not Complete. A Complete Envelope Requires Documents,
>   Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line.

```
{  
   "status":"sent",
   "compositeTemplates":[  
      {  
         "inlineTemplates":[  
            {  
               "sequence":"1",
               "recipients":{  
                  "signers":[  
                     {  
                        "name":"Dr. Oswald",
                        "email":"somewhere@google.com",
                        "accessCode":null,
                        "roleName":"recipient",
                        "clientUserId":"test",
                        "recipientId":"1",
                        "tabs":{  
                           "textTabs":[  
                              {  
                                 "tabLabel":"\\*recipientFullName",
                                 "value":"Grace Hooper",
                                 "tabId":null,
                                 "tabLocked":false
                              }
                           ],
                           "checkboxTabs":[  

                           ],
                           "titleTabs":[  

                           ]
                        },
                        "routingOrder":null
                     }
                  ],
                  "agents":[  

                  ]
               },
               "customFields":null
            }
         ],
         "document":{  
            "name":"HIA",
            "documentId":1,
            "documentBase64":"...",
            "transformPdfFields":true
         }
      }
   ],
   "notification":null
}
```

but adding a server template - works. According to the docs a `ServerTemplate` is not required on a `CompositeTemplate`. This request is OK:

```
 {
   "status":"sent",
   "compositeTemplates":[
      {
         "serverTemplates":[ // THIS IS THE ONLY ADDITION
            {
               "sequence":"0",
               "templateId":"ASDASDASD-SD-SADS-AA9A-ASD"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates":[
            {
               "sequence":"1",
               "recipients":{
                  "signers":[
                     {
                        "name":"Dr. Oswald",
                        "email":"someone@google.com",
                        "accessCode":null,
                        "roleName":"recipient",
                        "clientUserId":"test",
                        "recipientId":"1",
                        "tabs":{
                           "textTabs":[
                              {
                                 "tabLabel":"\\*recipientFullName",
                                 "value":"Grace Hooper",
                                 "tabId":null,
                                 "tabLocked":false
                              }
                           ],
                           "checkboxTabs":[

                           ],
                           "titleTabs":[

                           ]
                        },
                        "routingOrder":null
                     }
                  ],
                  "agents":[

                  ]
               },
               "customFields":null
            }
         ],
         "document":{
            "name":"HIA",
            "documentId":1,
            "documentBase64":"...",
            "transformPdfFields":true
         }
      }
   ],
   "notification":null
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message here was correctly reporting, I needed to add an email subject and the issue was solved. Empty strings do not work.

> A Complete Envelope Requires Documents, Recipients, Tabs, and a Subject Line.

Adding an `emailSubject` to the request solved this.

Comment: Great, would be appreciated if you could accept this as the answer for the benefit of the community... thx

Comment: Done thanks for the reminder and your helpful answers on docusign api!